# Setting cookies with $_SERVER info

Tags: php, cookies, pathinfo

I'm trying to set a cookie which tracks what page the user is on, so that I can forward this in a websocket header, however when I do this:

```
setcookie("PAGE", $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 0, "/");
```

Which should be setting a cookie to something like %2FCommission%2F1 (/Commission/1), creates the cookie, which shows in firefox developer tools for a split second, then disappears (it doesn't show at all in chrome developer tools).

But if I manually set the cookie value as such:

```
setcookie("PAGE", "%2FCommission%2F1", 0, "/");
```

The cookie works perfectly fine.

I have tried trimming $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], along with replacing potentially problematic parts, but nothing seems to work, if $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is used in any capacity in the creation of the string passed into the cookie value, I get this behaviour. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your not actually setting the cookie by using `0`, your just sending it to be discarded by the browser. If its a websocket, why not get it from `window.location.pathname`?

Comment: The expiration of 0 actually makes it expire when the user closes their browser. But you make a fair point, I probably could just make the cookie on the client-side. Don't know why I didn't think of that. I still kinda want to get to the bottom of this strange behaviour though.

Comment: Oops yeah your right, how is the url structured? as if your using `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` it will only contain the value if you have a url like `index.php/Commission/1` (everything after .php)

Comment: Maybe you're after `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead.

Comment: Are you sure there is a $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']. Because at many servers there is no such thing. Better to use other SERVER values.

Comment: There is definitely a $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], and REQUEST_URI causes the exact same behaviour. Also, the URL is structured domain.tld/OvOcommissions/Commission/1 with PATH_INFO giving /Commission/1 because of my nginx configuration.